# What is the concept of concurrent pipelines (One parallel job in Azure Pipeline lets you run a single build or release job at any given time)?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, build-pipeline

I am reading about Concurrent pipelines in azure.

> Concurrent pipelines
>   You can run concurrent pipelines (also called parallel jobs) in Azure
>   Pipelines. One parallel job in Azure Pipeline lets you run a single
>   build or release job at any given time. This rule is true whether you
>   run the job on Microsoft-hosted or self-hosted agents. Parallel jobs
>   are purchased at the organization level, and they are shared by all
>   projects in an organization.

My understanding is that - the azure build pipeline is organized into jobs (either agent/agentless jobs). Each job contains tasks. On auto/manual trigger the build pipeline runs and I thought that the number of pipelines that can run in parallel (assuming each pipeline has got only 1 job in them) depends on the availability of build agents (machines - either azure or hosted).

So what exactly is the concept of concurrent pipelines? What is the meaning of "One parallel job in Azure Pipeline lets you run a single build or release job at any given time."? In simple English, buying One **parallel** job should allow us to either a) run 2 build pipelines (assuming each pipeline contains only 1 job) or b) 1 pipeline with 2 jobs in parallel simultaneously. But this depends on availability of build agent as each pipeline (with 1 job) or 1 pipeline with 2 jobs will need 2 machines to run parallelly. Does it also mean that by default (free of charge) only one build pipeline can run at a time? There seems to be confusion between parallel job and parallel pipeline because one pipeline can have parallel job.

I need clarity on this topic with respect to pipeline/job/parallel pipeline/parallel job/count of build agents/count of parallel jobs.

Answer (score 1):

> I need clarity on this topic with respect to pipeline/job/parallel
>   pipeline/parallel job/count of build agents/count of parallel jobs.

Check [Relationship between jobs and parallel jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops#relationship-between-jobs-and-parallel-jobs):

*1.When you define a pipeline, you can define it as a collection of jobs. When a pipeline runs, you can run multiple jobs as part of that pipeline.*

*2.Each job consumes a parallel job that runs on an agent. When there aren't enough parallel jobs available for your organization, the jobs are queued up and run one after the other.*

So if we have a pipeline with two jobs: When I queue the pipeline,these two jobs **can't run at the same time** if we only have one parallel job.

There're different count of parallel jobs available for microsoft-hosted and self-hosted agents, you can follow [View available parallel jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops#view-available-parallel-jobs) to check the parallel jobs you have.

And for count of build agents, there's no count limit for microsoft-hosted agents. If you're meaning self-hosted agents, you can own many agents in your agent pool.(The limit of count is something we won't meet in normal situation.) We can also install more than one agents in same local machine, see [Can I install multiple self-hosted agents on the same machine?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#can-i-install-multiple-self-hosted-agents-on-the-same-machine).

Hope all above helps :)

Comment: I had expected one parallel job should allow two jobs to run because that is what parallel means.

Comment: I also thought 0 parallel jobs should mean 1 job. 1 parallel means 2 jobs. 2 parallel means 4 jobs. And so on..

Comment: Hmm, but actually... `Each job consumes a parallel job that runs on an agent.`

Comment: @variable Agree that the name of `parallel job` is a bit misleading... And to answer your first comment, see [tip1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops#microsoft-hosted-cicd) and [tip2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops#self-hosted-cicd). The count differs from hosted agent to self-hosted agent, from public project to private project...

Comment: @variable Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? If the puzzle still persists to block you, please feel free to let me know :)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Can one self-hosted agent on one machine run multiple jobs in parallel? Or do I need to install 2..n self-hosted agents on the same machine to run n jobs in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the agents don't run pipelines.
They run jobs.
So if you are allowed to run "2 concurrent pipelines", it must mean 2 parallel jobs.
These jobs can be in a single pipeline if they are allowed to run in parallel (i.e. the other is not dependent on the first one).

Yes, on the free version it seems only one job can run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when this was released, but there is a setting in the Pre-deployment conditions of an environment that fixed this for me.  (Same place  you'd find Triggers, Pre-depoyment approvals, Gates)

Pre-deployment conditions >> Deployment queue settings >> Number of parallel deployments = 1 Specific = Maximum number of parallel deployments = 1.

[image: Screenshot]